# Send a message and receive answer with WebSocket client in C#

Tags: c#, websocket, client

I am trying to implement a WebSocket client in C#. I created a class named WSConnection, which creates the WebSocketClient object and connects it to a server via a ConnectAsync() method. The handshake seems to work, as the socket state, after it, is set to "open".

The problem starts when I try to send the first request to the server (I need to send a specific connect request to validate the connection and authenticate myself). When I try to do it, the program stays stuck on the ReceiveAsync() line in the Receive() method, which means, if I understood well, that no message is received from the server.

Here is the code of the WSConnection class :

```
class WSConnection
{
    private const string url = "ws://...";
    private string authenticationKey;
    private ClientWebSocket ws;

    public WSConnection(string key)
    {
        this.authenticationKey = key;
        this.ws = new ClientWebSocket();
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        while(ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(url), CancellationToken.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Web socket : " + ws.State);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending connect request...");

            // Send the connect request and wait for the response
            await Send("connect");
            await Receive();
        }
    }

    public async Task Send(string type)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        // We send a connect request
        if (type == "connect")
        {
            message.Append("type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("authentication") + "&");
            message.Append("authenticationKey=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(authenticationKey));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No valid message type");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Send message : " + message.ToString());
        var sendBuffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message.ToString()));
        await ws.SendAsync(sendBuffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    public async Task Receive()
    {
        ArraySegment<byte> receivedBytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(receivedBytes, CancellationToken.None);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedBytes.Array, 0, result.Count));
    }
}
```

After it, I simply call the Connect() method with an await in the main.

I suppose that I don't receive any message from the server because I don't send a correct one, so the question is how do I have to change the message I send ?

Thank you by advance.

**EDIT**

As Juan suggested, I used Fiddler to see the frames, and I got 2 corresponding frames :

[First frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyzaH.png)

[Second frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqnHs.png)

Again, I can't give the URL I'm trying to reach, so I blured it and the rest, but for what I'm looking for, the host is ok.

Comment: Are you positive the other side is receiving the request?

Comment: I can't really tell. That is part of the problem, I don't see what the server is receiving. But the handshake is ok, and the server is supposed to send back an error, if it receives a wrong request. Right know it doesn't send anything back, apparently.

Comment: Can you post the URL you are trying to reach? (if it's not private information). Please include the protocol you are trying to use. You need to determine if the request is even being received before you try to fix anything. Check this out and let us know: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718660/Debug-Inspect-WebSocket-traffic-with-Fiddler

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the URL. But I will follow this article and come back when it is done.

Comment: I followed the article @Juan gave me, and I edited the post to add it.

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems like no message is sent. Only the handshake and the upgrade to WebSocket request.

Comment: Can you post the output of the console? Also, Have you debugged this? Do you actually get to the Send("connect") line?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. Yes, I debugged it. The console writes 3 lines : the "state : open", the "Sending connect request..." and the content of the sent message (nothing more). For the debugging, I checked it, and I can confirm it goes through all the Send("connect") function, and enter in Receive(). It stays stuck there on the second line (the ReceiveAsync). It never reaches the Console.WriteLine instruction just behind.